# Object of type QueryResponse is not JSON serializable - Python 3.9 fastAPI using Pinecone

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, typeerror, fastapi

Given the following API response from pinecone (https://www.pinecone.io/docs/api/operation/query/)

```
results = {'matches': [{'id': 'yral5m',
              'metadata': {'subreddit': '2qkq6',
                           'text': 'Black Friday SaaS Deals - 2022'},
              'score': 0.772717535,
              'sparseValues': {},
              'values': []},
             {'id': 'yqypa5',
              'metadata': {'subreddit': '2qkq6',
                           'text': 'B2B sales interface.'},
              'score': 0.74192214,
              'sparseValues': {},
              'values': []}],
 'namespace': ''}
```

i am simply trying to return the JSON results from a function. (from a service to a controller) and getting a range of errors:

doing so with:

`return results` yields  `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

`return json.dumps(results)` yeilds `TypeError: Object of type QueryResponse is not JSON serializable`

*QueryResponse is the type returned from pinecone

`return jsonpickle.encode(query_results)` yeilds `"null"`

Very lost any advice would be appreciated!!

full code example:

Controller:

```
@router.post("/query/")
async def semantic_search(query: str, ):
result = await TopicQueryService.query(query)
return result
```

Service method:

```
    @staticmethod
    async def query(query) -> str:
    index = PineConeService.get_or_create_index("openai")
    embed = GPT3Service.get_embedding(query)
    query_results = index.query(
        vector=embed,
        top_k=2,
        include_metadata=True
    )
    return json.dumps(query_results)
```

Replacing Service Method query results with the logged response from index. query works fine eg below. Leading me to believe it is due to the QueryResponse object pinecone returns.

```
    @staticmethod
async def query(query) -> str:
    index = PineConeService.get_or_create_index("openai")
    embed = GPT3Service.get_embedding(query)
    logger.info(embed)
    query_results = {'matches': [{'id': 'yral5m',
                                  'metadata': {'subreddit': '2qkq6',
                                               'text': 'Black Friday SaaS Deals - 2022'},
                                  'score': 0.772717535,
                                  'sparseValues': {},
                                  'values': []},
                                 {'id': 'yqypa5',
                                  'metadata': {'subreddit': '2qkq6',
                                               'text': 'B2B sales interface.'},
                                  'score': 0.74192214,
                                  'sparseValues': {},
                                  'values': []}],
                     'namespace': ''}
    return json.dumps(query_results)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your code? To better understand why this errors could be occured

Comment: going to need some code samples. its not clear what issue you are having. for example the object you shared is  json serializable.

Comment: Hey i haver added some further examples! i am sure it must have something to do with the response type index.query returns. if i print it out, its exactly what i have shown above. if i then copy and past the json object it prints and paste it in place of the api call it all works fine. i added this example aswell

Comment: @Chris agree i have just deleted that as its already causing me issues... i have gone through that post, it wasnt quite it, `return query_results` gives `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

new solution is just iterating over and building my own object like so, does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Please have a closer look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804). If your object is already serialised, you can return a custom `Response` directly. No need to have FastAPI serialise it again; hence, in this case, you don't have to use `return json.dumps(blah)`. It is ok to loop over the results and create a `list`, but it might also be worth trying to find out what is causing the [`RecursionError`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53786145) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52873067) as well).

Comment: As the object is already been serialized. Simply use:
        matches = query_response['matches']
        for match in matches:
            match_id = match['id']
            score = match['score']
            values = match['values']
            # Do something with the match information
            print(f"Match ID: {match_id}, Score: {score}, Values: {values}")
And you can parse it smoothly ~

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `.to_dict()` from the QueryResponse object:

```
  @staticmethod
    async def query(query) -> str:
    index = PineConeService.get_or_create_index("openai")
    embed = GPT3Service.get_embedding(query)
    query_results = index.query(
        vector=embed,
        top_k=2,
        include_metadata=True
    )
    return json.dumps(query_results.to_dict())
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing that (i.e., `return json.dumps(query_results.to_dict())`). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804), as well as the links provided in the comments section above, for more details and examples.

Comment: As the object is already been serialized. Simply use:
        matches = query_response['matches']
        for match in matches:
            match_id = match['id']
            score = match['score']
            values = match['values']
            # Do something with the match information
            print(f"Match ID: {match_id}, Score: {score}, Values: {values}")
And you can parse it smoothly ~

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a solution -> just iterate over and build an object to return, not ideal though

```
``blah = []
  for x in query_results.matches:
    blah.append({
    "id": x.id,
    "metadata": x.metadata,
     "score": x.score
    })
 json.dumps(blah)``
```